# Ipad Safari rendering issue on dynamic generated javascript controls

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, canjs, canjs-view

I have a weird rendering issue on iPad Safari on iOs 9.2 (current, but on other versions too).

I have a dynamic autocomplete dropdown that is rendered via CanJs framework and the EJS template system. On Safari I get a weird line over the input when my dropdown is closed (that is, the dropdown is opened, and then is closed).

[image: wild line appears]

The thing is this: after I do a scroll down (so that the input is not visible anymore in the viewport), and then scroll back up, that line disappears:

[image: the line disappears]

Can you please point me to some information related to this issue, or does anyone else has encountered this kind of rendering issues?

I'm using the CanJs javascript framework as a client MVC, and it uses the EJS template rendering system. Another thing is this: it doesn't reproduce on other iPad browsers, neither on Android, nor on desktop environment.